# What directories are there other than the temp folder(in appdata)?

Tags: uac

Are there directories other than appdata that I can drop files to without UAC privileges?Or is the AppData place the only location?

Answer (score 0):

Users can write to anywhere in their profile. E.g.:

- `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY)` e.g. C:\Users\User0\Desktop
- `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)` e.g. C:\Users\User0\Documents
- `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA)` e.g. C:\Users\User0\AppData
- `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA)` e.g. C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local

As well as the Common AppData folder:

- `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)` e.g. C:\ProgramData